# AdMob Interstitial Ad always return null

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to implement an interstitial Ad activity insite my application whic is called every time that the user opens the settings.

The prblem is that even if the Ad unit ID is correct and the ad loading code is the same as google shows in their documentation the interstital ad doesn't load and always returns null.

I Also thought that maybe the app didn't have enough time to load the ad and then show it between the transaction from MainActivity to SettingsActivity, so i tried to start the IntersttitalAd with a PostDelayed runnable handler, but didn't work either.

Can anyone tell me why?

This is the InterstitialAdActivity:

```
public class InterstitialadActivity extends Activity {
private final String TAG = "Interstitialad debug";
private ProgressDialog progress;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Loading Ad");
    progress.setMessage("Wait while loading Interstitial Ad...");
    progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
    progress.show();

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    InterstitialAd.load(
            this,
            AD_UNIT,
            adRequest,
            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                    // an ad is loaded.
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                    interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                            new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                    // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                    // show it a second time.
                                    Log.d(TAG, "The ad was dismissed.");
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                    finish();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                    // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                    // show it a second time.
                                    Log.d(TAG, "The ad failed to show.");
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                    finish();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                    // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                                    Log.d(TAG, "The ad was shown.");
                                }
                            });
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error
                    String error =
                            String.format(
                                    "domain: %s, code: %d, message: %s",
                                    loadAdError.getDomain(), loadAdError.getCode(), loadAdError.getMessage());
                    Log.d(TAG,"onAdFailedToLoad() with error: " + error);

                    mInterstitialAd = null;

                }
            });

    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        mInterstitialAd.show(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"ad was shown");

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"ad was null");
        progress.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
}
```

And this is how i call it the SettingsActivity:

```
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
           ...
    if(!MainActivity.isPro) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, InterstitialadActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should request test ads first to check if the implementation was done correctly.

Comment: Once you see test ads, you're good to go. You can remove the testDevice method from the request builder then.

Comment: And once you have published the app on the play store, you wait for a few days and your users will see the ads.

Comment: and finally, check your console tab and I bet you'll get the reason for ads not being shown to you !!